# How to use css for the table to appear side by side with other content

Tags: css-float

I am a novice at this so please any assistance will be grateful. I want to have a page like this www.bimslivinggardens.com with a table below picture slide show on the left and information on the right side by side. Please how should I go about doing this?

Comment: Have you googled for "CSS layout"? what did you find?

Answer (score 0):

Read http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/3-column-layout-code/
It will explain houw to setup a 3 column layout properly.

I would however change the p's to div's, since i feel the p's are misused there.